# What is wrong in this jsoup code? (Android)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

This is the code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

private TextView textView2;

private Button button2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url="http://stackoverflow.com/";
                try{
                Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements elem=doc.select("meta[name=twitter:domain]");
                        String title1=elem.attr("content");
                        textView2.setText(title1);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    });
}}
```

This is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jsouptest.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="100dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Display" />
```

It isn't displaying the content in the textview on clicking the 
button.
I have added permission for internet in the manifest file.

Comment: Did u debug for the thread, if it is coming inside the on click listener. If this is coming is the code is it throwing any exception(Log exception in catch block) .. look out in logcat logs for errors.

Comment: i'm not sure what is jsoup but you are trying to make network related things in main thread

Comment: Relax !! There is no problem in your jsoup code.. There is some other error !!

Comment: add a *Log* or *StackTrace* in your *catch{}* to see if there is an Exception

Answer (score 0):

You can not call Network on main thread. You must call async task to make network calls. When you click on button execute a async task and then do your stuff there.

Below Code will Help:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new GetStringTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class GetStringTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements elem = doc.getElementsByTag("title");
                String title1 = elem.html();
                return title1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            textView1.setText(title);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the code above sets the TextView label to "Stack Overflow".

Comment: Thank you Ashu, the code worked. But i didn't understand why we write "elem.html()".

Comment: Element.html gives the inner html. The code i wrote in the sample code is just an example to get the inner html of the title tag. You can have your own selectors and do stuff with them.

Comment: Hi ashu, Can you help me with the new code i have posted above. It is not displaying the image in imageview, which i'm trying to get from imgur.